# In C# WinForms how can I assign a labeltext for a few seconds and remove it again, without interrupting the execution of the other code?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm creating a todolist program, where you can add a task, and when it's done you check a checkbox, click update and the task is removed from the list (completed).

I have created a gamifying version, where you get XP points for every task that you complete. I simply calculate XP from the length of task string. The total XP is then shown in the WinForm on a label text.

Then I got the idea that I want the label that shows the total XP, to show the XP gained from a task, just for a few seconds, and then show the total XP again.

I just dont know how to do that without having the entire code wait the few seconds as well. I guess it needs to run in a separate thread, which I have no experience with.

```
1) XPlabel shows: 1455 XP
2) User completes task
3) XPlabel shows for 2 seconds: +254 XP
4) XPlabel shows: 1709 XP
```

*All while the rest of the code doesn't wait those 2 seconds, but keeps running, doing it's other tasks. Like updating the data store text file.*

But doing that as I mentioned will give a laggy experience, because the other code that writes / deletes from the data text file, where I store the tasks, will have to wait the few seconds as well. The entire user interface will be on hold for those few seconds.

So...

Is there a way I can do this while the code keeps running?

CODE EXCERPT:

```
//removes checked items
                foreach (string item in todolistCheckbox.CheckedItems)
                {
                    string strFilePath = "tododo.data";
                    string strSearchText = item;
                    string strOldText;
                    string n = "";
                    StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(strFilePath);
                    while ((strOldText = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        if (!strOldText.Equals(strSearchText))
                        {
                            n += strOldText + Environment.NewLine;
                        }
                        //XP Calculation
                        xpread();
        I WANT -->      xplabel.text = xp; --- 2 seconds
                        int x;
                        Int32.TryParse(xp, out x);
                        int buffxp = strOldText.Length * 8 + x;
                        string xpupd = buffxp.ToString();
                        //write
                        xpwrite(xpupd);
                        xpupdate(xpupd);
                        levelup(xpupd);
                    }
                    sr.Close();
                    File.WriteAllText(strFilePath, n);

                }
```

/Cheers

Comment: Sounds like you need to thread that code away from other thread(s) and synchronize with the gui thread. Are you even using multiple threads? From your code and problem description I'd think not. That's a huge problem when it comes to GUIs as the window will become "frozen" while it waits for whatever code your running to complete.

Comment: I was just about to suggest threads, create a new thread to handle the other process while the first thread continues running simultaneously.

Comment: Use an `async` method.

Comment: Does the async method run in like its own thread then?

Comment: @MikaelPuusaari he really needs to get everything that isn't related to the gui to be threaded away from the gui.

Comment: @Jim if he does that he'll have to create a new task every time he wants to update his label which eats time and possibly creates race conditions and opens the possibility for deadlocks.

Comment: @RichardBarker Can I create a thread for just that task, or do I need to wrap the entire code in threads? Sorry threads is an unexplored territory for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a **ThreadPool** to spin it on another thread and have it manage itself.

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(myFunction), xp);
```

---

```
public void myFunction(object state)
{
  int xp = (int)state;

  myLabel.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => myLabel.SelectedText = xp)); //Thread Safe Label Updater
  new System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(false).WaitOne(2000); //Wait 2 Seconds
  myLabel.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => myLabel.SelectedText = string.Empty)); //Sets the label to empty. Could also be used to put back to totalXP
}
```

And any additional options you may need.

EDIT: Be sure to include `using System.Threading`for any threading that you do

Comment: Very interesting! I get an error on ThreadPool doesnt exist in current context and WaitCallback could not be found. The public void function seems to work without errors.

Comment: Be sure to call ThreadPool from a method (not just from inside your class) and to include System.Threading

Comment: Yeessss!! This did it. It works! Thanks man! :o)  Also a thanks to the other contributors.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Task` for this purpose:

```
xplabel.Text = "+254";

// 2 second pause
Task.Delay(2000)
    // after 2 second continue execution
    .ContinueWith(t => { xplabel.Text = "1709"; },
        CancellationToken.None,
        TaskContinuationOptions.None,
        // execution will be in GUI context, i.e. safe
        TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Don't forget

```
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
```

Comment: Cool I'll try out that variant as well. Thanks :)

Comment: This will throw `InvalidOperationException`  because of Cross-thread operation. - Fix the answer.

Comment: Ok. Rewrote it simpler.